# Wordpress Loop Creating Blank Space at Start of Page Loop

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

On my single page blog posts, wordpress is creating this random empty (what I believe to be a) div. Could it possibly be the way I made my post loop? Not sure why this behavior is happening. If someone wants a link to see it in person, just comment. I am building the theme on my local machine, but I could put it on a live site if need be.

PHP:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Single Blog Page */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="page-content">

<?php

if( have_posts() ):
    while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>


<div class="single-post">
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <small>Posted On: <?php the_time( 'F j, Y' ); ?> in <?php the_category(); ?></small>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
</div>
<hr>

</div>

    <?php endwhile;

endif;

?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

CSS:

```
.single-post {
    padding: 1em;
    border: 0.1em solid black;
}
```

Rendered HTML:

```
    <!-- Links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/ericshio/style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="" />

    <!-- Meta -->

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- Title -->

    <title>Eric Shio</title>

    <!-- WP Head -->

        <meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Eric Shio     &raquo; Test Comments Feed"     href="http://localhost:8888/2016/08/04/test/feed/" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window._wpemojiSettings =          {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/72x72\/","ext":".png","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.5.3"}};
        !function(a,b,c){function d(a){var     c,d,e,f=b.createElement("canvas"),g=f.getContext&&f.getContext("2d"),h=Stri     ng.fromCharCode;if(!g||!g.fillText)return!1;switch(g.textBaseline="top",g.f    ont="600 32px Arial",a){case"flag":return     g.fillText(h(55356,56806,55356,56826),0,0),f.toDataURL().length>3e3;case"di     versity":return   g.fillText(h(55356,57221),0,0),c=g.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data,d=c[0]+","+   c[1]+","+c[2]+","+c[3],g.fillText(h(55356,57221,55356,57343),0,0),c=g.getIm  ageData(16,16,1,1).data,e=c[0]+","+c[1]+","+c[2]+","+c[3],d!==e;case"simple":return g.fillText(h(55357,56835),0,0),0!==g.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0];case"unicode8":return g.fillText(h(55356,57135),0,0),0!==g.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0]}return!1}function e(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var f,g,h,i;for(i=Array("simple","flag","unicode8","diversity"),c.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},h=0;h<i.length;h++)c.supports[i[h]]=d(i[h]),c.supports.everything=c.supports.everything&&c.supports[i[h]],"flag"!==i[h]&&(c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&c.supports[i[h]]);c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!c.supports.flag,c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.everything||(g=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",g,!1),a.addEventListener("load",g,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",g),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),f=c.source||{},f.concatemoji?e(f.concatemoji):f.wpemoji&&f.twemoji&&(e(f.twemoji),e(f.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
display: inline !important;
border: none !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
height: 1em !important;
width: 1em !important;
margin: 0 .07em !important;
vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
background: none !important;
padding: 0 !important;
}
   </style>
     <link rel='stylesheet' id='open-sans-css'     href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C300%2C400%2C600&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=4.5.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
   <link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'   href='http://localhost:8888/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.5.3'  type='text/css' media='all' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://localhost:8888/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.5.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' id='ericshiostyle-css'  href='http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/ericshio/style.css?ver=4.5.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
 <link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='http://localhost:8888/wp-json/' />
 <link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://localhost:8888/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
 <link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://localhost:8888/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
 <link rel='prev' title='Hello world!' href='http://localhost:8888/2016/08/02/hello-world/' />
 <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.5.3" />
 <link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:8888/2016/08/04/test/" />
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://localhost:8888/?p=48' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="http://localhost:8888/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2F2016%2F08%2F04%2Ftest%2F" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="http://localhost:8888/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2F2016%2F08%2F04%2Ftest%2F&#038;format=xml" />
<style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }       </style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
* html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
@media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
    html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
}
</style>
 </head>

    <!-- Body -->

<body class="single single-post postid-48 single-format-standard logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support wp-custom-logo">

    <!-- Site Header -->
<header class="site-header">
  <a href="http://localhost:8888/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url"><img width="257" height="239" src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/TEXT-FILM-STRIP.png" class="site-branding" alt="TEXT FILM STRIP" itemprop="logo" /></a>            <div class="menu-main-navigation-container"><ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="main-navigation"><li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="http://localhost:8888/">Overview</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-22"><a href="http://localhost:8888/expeditions/">Expeditions</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20"><a href="http://localhost:8888/expeditions/vancouver/">Vancouver</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="http://localhost:8888/expeditions/seattle/">Seattle</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current_page_parent menu-item-27"><a href="http://localhost:8888/blog/">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33"><a href="http://localhost:8888/about/">About</a>    </li>
 <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23"><a href="http://localhost:8888/contact/">Contact</a></li>
 </ul></div>    </header>
    <!-- /Site Header -->

<!-- Container -->
<div class="container">

<!-- Site Content -->


<div id="page-content">
</div>

<!-- /Site Content -->

</div>

<!-- /Container -->
<div id="page-content">



<div class="single-post">
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <small>Posted On: August 4, 2016 in <ul class="post-categories">
<li><a href="http://localhost:8888/category/uncategorized/" rel="category tag">Uncategorized</a></li></ul></small>
    <p><p>Stuff</p>
</p>
</div>
<hr>

</div>


<!-- Footer -->

<footer class="site-footer">
<p><a href="mailto:hello@ericshio.com">hello@ericshio.com</a> &copy; Eric Shiozaki</p>
 <div id="footer-sidebar" class="secondary">
 <div id="footer-sidebar1">
 </div>
 <div id="footer-sidebar2">
 </div>
 <div id="footer-sidebar3">
 </div>
 </div>   
 </footer>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js?ver=4.5.3'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/ericshio/js/ericshio.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.5.3'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var request, b = document.body, c = 'className', cs = 'customize-support', rcs = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)(no-)?'+cs+'(\\s+|$)');

        request = true;

        b[c] = b[c].replace( rcs, ' ' );
        b[c] += ( window.postMessage && request ? ' ' : ' no-' ) + cs;
    }());
</script>
        <div id="wpadminbar" class="nojq nojs">
                        <a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="#wp-toolbar" tabindex="1">Skip to toolbar</a>
                    <div class="quicklinks" id="wp-toolbar" role="navigation" aria-label="Toolbar" tabindex="0">
            <ul id="wp-admin-bar-root-default" class="ab-top-menu">
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item"  aria-haspopup="true" href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/about.php"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="screen-reader-text">About WordPress</span></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-default" class="ab-submenu">
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-about"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/about.php">About WordPress</a>     </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-external" class="ab-sub-secondary ab-submenu">
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-wporg"><a class="ab-item"  href="https://wordpress.org/">WordPress.org</a>     </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-documentation"><a class="ab-item"  href="https://codex.wordpress.org/">Documentation</a>       </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-support-forums"><a class="ab-item"  href="https://wordpress.org/support/">Support Forums</a>       </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-feedback"><a class="ab-item"  href="https://wordpress.org/support/forum/requests-and-feedback">Feedback</a>        </li></ul></div>        </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-site-name" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item"  aria-haspopup="true" href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/">Eric Shio</a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-site-name-default" class="ab-submenu">
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-dashboard"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/">Dashboard</a>        </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-appearance" class="ab-submenu">
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-themes"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/themes.php">Themes</a>        </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-widgets"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/widgets.php">Widgets</a>     </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-menus"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/nav-menus.php">Menus</a>       </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-background" class="hide-if-customize"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/themes.php?page=custom-background">Background</a>       </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-header" class="hide-if-customize"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/themes.php?page=custom-header">Header</a>       </li></ul></div>        </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-customize" class="hide-if-no-customize"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/customize.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2F2016%2F08%2F04%2Ftest%2F">Customize</a>     </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-comments"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/edit-comments.php"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span id="ab-awaiting-mod" class="ab-label awaiting-mod pending-count count-0" aria-hidden="true">0</span><span class="screen-reader-text">0 comments awaiting moderation</span></a>        </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-content" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item"  aria-haspopup="true" href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/post-new.php"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">New</span></a>           

 <div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-new-content-default" class="ab-submenu">
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-post"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/post-new.php">Post</a>      </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-media"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/media-new.php">Media</a>       </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-page"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page">Page</a>         </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-user"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/user-new.php">User</a>      </li></ul>    </div>        </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/post.php?post=48&#038;action=edit">Edit Post</a>        </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-top-secondary" class="ab-top-secondary ab-top-menu">
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-search" class="admin-bar-search"><div class="ab-item ab-empty-item" tabindex="-1"><form action="http://localhost:8888/" method="get" id="adminbarsearch"><input class="adminbar-input" name="s" id="adminbar-search" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" /><label for="adminbar-search" class="screen-reader-text">Search</label><input type="submit" class="adminbar-button" value="Search"/></form></div>       </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-my-account" class="menupop with-avatar"><a class="ab-item"  aria-haspopup="true" href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/profile.php">Howdy, @eshiozaki<img alt='' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/dda9d12be8829bad13acdbde559319b0?s=26&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/dda9d12be8829bad13acdbde559319b0?s=52&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-26 photo' height='26' width='26' /></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-user-actions" class="ab-submenu">
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-user-info"><a class="ab-item" tabindex="-1" href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/profile.php"><img alt='' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/dda9d12be8829bad13acdbde559319b0?s=64&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/dda9d12be8829bad13acdbde559319b0?s=128&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-64 photo' height='64' width='64' /><span class='display-name'>@eshiozaki</span></a>        </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit-profile"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/profile.php">Edit My Profile</a>                 </li>
    <li id="wp-admin-bar-logout"><a class="ab-item"  href="http://localhost:8888/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=cc2d8b5dfd">Log Out</a>       </li></ul></div>             </li></ul>         </div>
                    <a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="http://localhost:8888/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=cc2d8b5dfd">Log Out</a>
                </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, else it is difficult to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: One moment :) It's a long one :P

Comment: It doesn't look like this template is causing the issue. Do you have <div id="page-content"> in your header.php, or some other template file that's also loading? It's showing <!-- Site Content --> comments that aren't in your template above.

Comment: page content is in the index.php file, I guess a better place to put it would be the header.php?

Comment: If I only have it in the header than the content is no longer in my specified <div id="page-content"> area

Comment: since I have a vertical header on the left it displays full-width and goes under it

Comment: I added the container area and closed in the footer and now it works without that div in the index.php

Comment: Wow, fixing the container fixed like 3 other of my issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change .single-post to div.single-post so that it does not affect the body. For some reason the body tag is getting assigned the class single-post, so to avoid this I only target the div.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, the closing div was not quite in the right spot. Here ya go!

```
<?php endwhile;
endif;
?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Be sure to remove the wrong div (above the endwhile)

Comment: You may also want to move the <hr>, either between endwhile; and endif; (if you want an <hr> between each single-post), or after the endif (if you only want it once at the end).

Comment: There is still that empty box above posts. :P

Comment: Have you tried inspect element to see what it is printing out? Could you link us to a live copy? Interested in helping you.

Comment: Here it is: http://www.ericshio.com/2016/08/02/wordpress-resources-at-siteground/